# grouping every N values

Tags: postgresql, group-by, aggregation

I have a table like this in PostgreSQL. I want to perform aggregation functions like mean and max for every 16 records based on ID (which is primary key). For example I have to calculate mean value for first 16 records and second 16 records and so on.

```
+-----+-------------
| ID  |  rainfall  |
+-----+----------- |
|  1  |  110.2     |
|  2  |  56.6      |
|  3  |  65.6      |
|  4  |  75.9      |
+-----+------------
```

Comment: Sample data padded out a bit: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/0bffb

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The 1st approach that comes to mind is to use `row_number()` to annotate the table, then group by blocks of 16 rows.

```
SELECT min(id) as first_id, max(id) AS last_id, avg(rainfall) AS avg_this_16
FROM (
  SELECT id, rainfall, row_number() OVER (order by id) AS n
  FROM the_table
) x(id,rainfall,n)
GROUP BY n/16
ORDER BY n/16;
```

Note that this won't necessarily include 16 samples for the last group.

Alternately you can calculate a *running average* by using `avg()` as a window function:

```
SELECT id, avg(rainfall) OVER (ORDER BY id ROWS 15 PRECEDING)
FROM the_table;
```

... possibly annotating that with the row number and selecting the ones you want:

```
SELECT id AS greatest_id_in_group, avg_last_16_inclusive FROM (
  SELECT
    id, 
    avg(rainfall) OVER (ORDER BY id ROWS 15 PRECEDING) AS avg_last_16_inclusive,
    row_number() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS n
  FROM the_table
) x WHERE n % 16 = 0;
```

This will disregard the last n<16 samples, not returning a row for them.

Note that I'm assuming the IDs aren't guaranteed to be contiguous. If they are gap-less, you can just `group by id/16` and avoid the window function.

Comment: my records are more than 500 always. The IDs are consecutive without gaps but some of the rainfall values are null values. Your approach is quite working for me. Thank you

Comment: I'm using your first approach by row_number(), but i'm not quite understand it. I need clarification in the following lines and explanation about why they are used please: 'row_number() OVER (order by id) AS n' and ') x(id,rainfall,n)' . and what is x in the second one?

Comment: @user1043898: `x(id,rainfall,n)` is an alias for the derived table that the SELECT produces, you need to give it a name so that you can refer to it and you need to give it a name even if you don't refer to it by name because SQL says so; the things in the parentheses name the derived table's columns (not necessary in this case but a reasonable habit). This might help you with window functions: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html

Comment: I imagine the last line should be like this: `) x WHERE n % 16 = 0;`

Comment: @user1043898 You're quite right, using % 1 results in the 1st record having only one sample, though it makes no difference from then on.

Comment: I made the `group by` using `(n-1)/4` instead of `n/4` since the number starts at 1.

Answer (score 0):

late answer, but anyway for reference

since `ID` was said to be continuos and gap-less, then this would result pretty straightforward

```
SELECT avg(rainfall),string_agg(id::text, ',')
FROM the_table
GROUP BY (id - 1) / 16;
```

notice the `(id - 1)` to get the grouping from zero to 15, otherwise first group may dephase

PS: @Craig Ringer gave a hint by the end of his answer, but didn't post is as code

> Note that I'm assuming the IDs aren't guaranteed to be contiguous. If they are gap-less, you can just group by id/16 and avoid the window function.